# How do I remove unused image from my xcode project?

Tags: xcode, image

When I delete images using Delete. It has two choices.. remove reference and move to trash.. when I choose move to trash, the image is removed from the list. But when I hit run, the image is still attached to the running app? Why is that? can someone help me with this issue? I want to remove it completely from my app.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning first?

Comment: In case cleaning doesn't help either delete the app from simulator as you would delete from a real device to re-install it on next Run

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the Xcode and Simulator and then Run it. Also try to remove Background image name from the Attributes Inspector. This might work